# Emulator for middleware android development for linux platform

Tags: android, c++, linux, middleware

I am experimenting with Android Binders at middleware level using C++ so I need an emulator to test it as I cannot afford a board everywhere. My ultimate target is to port a linux middleware application on android and I also want to test that app.

Is the android emulator that comes with SDK suitable for it (which I don't think). If no, is there any emulator for android middleware development or how can I test on my PC instead of running binaries on an ARM board?

Comment: For the one who downvoted, I asked **is there any emulator**, not **suggest a good emulator**. So its not opinion-based question. Please do not downvote.

Comment: I don't think the emulator isn't suitable. What do you mean with middleware? Between user and kernel (=android level)? Between android and user? Between kernel and android? Between user and some other kind of user-level software?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not rely on/do not want to change the HALs of specific hardware you should be perfectly able to use the emulator.

Depending on what kind of middleware you want to test you could either use the emulator coming with the sdk, create an avd and install your app/library there or you could modify the android source code (when your middleware should be part of thd system) and start the aosp provided emulator directly with thd built ROM.

Don't know if this answers the question as I didn't fully understand what you want to say with 'middleware'